# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I'm trying to display the data on the front end but i get the above error. How to resolve this?

> **service.ts**

```
rec_source(){
    var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    var options =  {
      headers: headers
  };
  return this.httpClient.get('api/recruit/fetch_recruitment_details',options)
  }
```

> **component.ts**

```
sources:any = [];

constructor(private Authentication:AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.Authentication.rec_source()
  .subscribe(source => {
    this.sources = source;
  });
}
```

> **component.html**

```
<table *ngIf="sources" class="row-border hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Data</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let source of sources">
    <td>{{ source}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

//the data that needs to be displayed

[image: the data that needs to be displayed]

//the error
[image: the error]

Comment: Please provide the code of RecruitmentDetailsComponent.html and corresponding ts file.

Comment: Thats what I have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api response is not an array or iterable, that what the error says. It is object, which is not iterable with `*ngFor`. Maybe you wanted to iterate `data_candidate_source` or `data_new_hiredate`. In such case you need to assign correct property to your `source` property in component:

```
this.sources = source.data_candidate_source
```

Or when you want to iterate through object then you can use newly added [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).