# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. in angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I trying to get data using web api in angular7  but i'm facing [object object] issue.

auth.service.ts

```
getCareer(){
    return this._HttpClient.get('http://localhost:49345/api/website/getCarrier');
    }
```

component.ts

```
export class careerComponent implements OnInit{

    getCareer$: object;

     constructor(private _AuthService: AuthService){ }

     ngOnInit(){
        this._AuthService.getCareer().subscribe(
        data => this.getCareer$ = data
    );
    }


}
```

component.html

```
<div class="col-xl-6" *ngFor="let career of getCareer$">
                    <h2>test</h2>
                    <h3>{{career.designation}}</h3>
                </div>
```

Issue/console screenshot

[image]

API Screenshot

[image]

How can i solve it?

Comment: i think u need to provide a type for the observable ( like an interface or class) or use map funciton, you will get some idea here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192815/map-doesnt-exist-on-observableobject-with-angular-6-0-0-and-rxjs-6-1-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error trying to diff '\[object Object\]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044045/error-trying-to-diff-object-object-only-arrays-and-iterables-are-allowed-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
`ngOnInit(){
    this._AuthService.getCareer().subscribe(
    data => { this.getCareer$ = data.data.map(item => {
            return item.designation
         })
});
}`
```

change the code as above..hope it will work.
now the getCareer$ contains all the designations

Comment: how to get in component.html?

Comment: <div class="col-xl-6" *ngFor="let career of getCareer$">
                    <h2>test</h2>
                    <h3>{{career}}</h3>
                </div>

Comment: can you please check data inside getCareer$ ?

Comment: `input = {"data":[{designation:"desig1"},{designation:"desig2"},{designation:"desig3"}]}`
this is the sample data i was trying with... and the code is                                 
                `expected  = input.data.map(item => {return item.designation})`